# ERROR dynamiccontroller.DynamicControllerManager [Grails]

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

What does this error mean? How can I solve it?

```
| Error 2013-08-15 14:39:55,130 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR dynamiccontroller.DynamicControllerManager  - 
No destination controller specified in the 'controller' property or
'grails.plugins.dynamicController.mixins' config attribute for PropertiesControllerMixin, ignoring
```

Comment: Did you changed your UrlMappings? Can you share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this blog post:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Upgrade-error-td3406164.html

Put this in your config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.dynamicController.mixins = [ 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.IndexControllerMixin':       'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.HibernateControllerMixin':   'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.Log4jControllerMixin' :      'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.SpringControllerMixin' :     'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.MemoryControllerMixin' :     'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.PropertiesControllerMixin' : 'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.ScopesControllerMixin' :     'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController', 
   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.ThreadsControllerMixin' :    'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController' 
]
```

Comment: for posterity, the third line changes for grails 2.4: `   'com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.appinfo.hibernate.HibernateControllerMixin':   'com.burtbeckwith.appinfo_test.AdminManageController',
`

Comment: nope, but it's fixable. In fact, I just put in a pull request for it.